# how to select text box value by using filter in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I am trying to type the text in a text box and I need to select this value for filtering. How can I select the text box value in angularJs

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">



      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>



</head>
<body ng-app="">
  <div ng-init="specialists = [{name:'aaaa', id:'555-1276'},
                         {name:'bbbb', id:'800-322-435'},
                         {name:'cccc', id:'555-4321'},
                         {name:'dddd', id:'555-5678'},
                         {name:'eeee', id:'555-8765'},
                         {name:'ffff', id:'555-3212'}
                        ]"></div>

<label>Search: <input ng-model="user.specialistSearch"></label>
<table>
  <tr><th>Name</th></tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="specialist in specialists | filter:user.specialistSearch">
    <td>{{specialist.name}}</td>

  </tr>
</table>
<hr>

</body>
</html>
```

here when im trying to type the text  i need select the value.How can i select the text box value in angular js

Comment: you can get $scope.user.specialistSearch in your controller

Comment: can you please explain briefly

Comment: where do you want that textbox value?

Comment: when i type the in text box cccc.cccc only dispalyed i want select the cccc send id only to controler

Comment: first comment is the answer

Comment: I tried but it is not coming.is there any reference  sites

Comment: How to send  a id through text box plz give some suggestion

Answer (score 0):

you have to just try this ....

```
 <div ng-init="specialists = [{name:'aaaa', id:'555-1276'},
                         {name:'bbbb', id:'800-322-435'},
                         {name:'cccc', id:'555-4321'},
                         {name:'dddd', id:'555-5678'},
                         {name:'eeee', id:'555-8765'},
                         {name:'ffff', id:'555-3212'}
                        ]"></div>


        <p><input type="text" ng-model="test"></p>

<table>
  <tr><th>Name</th></tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="specialist in specialists | filter:test">
    <td>{{specialist.name}}</td>

  </tr>
</table>
```